# How to save date field to Firebase using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, date, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to save a date field to Firebase, but I'm getting an error.

```
@IBAction func dateValueChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePicker.maximumDate = NSDate()
}


@IBAction func saveButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {


    self.ref.child("New Posts").child(userID!).setValue(["Diary:":textEntry.text, "Title:": titleEntry.text, "Date:": datePicker.date])
}
```

Error message:

```
Contextual type 'AnyObject' cannot be used with dictionary literal
```

Any ideas what I'm not doing? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend saving the date as Unix time (`timeIntervalSince1970`), though any standard date format should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't help with my saving the date field. How do I call the input from the DatePicker to my Firebase reference? datepicker.date doesn't work

Comment: Do you have a reference to your `datePicker` (a property in your class, for example)? You should be able to get the `date` from `datePicker.date` IIRC, then format as needed.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidatepicker/1615975-date

Comment: Yes I've referenced it. Input is definitely being received but Swift keeps giving me the "Contextual type 'AnyObject' cannot be used with dictionary literal" error on the self.ref.child line

Comment: Have you tried outputting your date as the unix time as I proposed? Second, you may need to cast that dictionary to `[String: Any]` to get around the warning.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the NSDate to NSNumber to save. And from NSNumber to NSDate to read. But be aware if you ever read or write from an Android app, you will need to convert the numeric value to unix style Timestamp which defines the origin date (zero value) as 1970. iOS represents the baseline slightly differently.